# no module named zlib

Tags: python, virtualenv, zlib, ubuntu-10.10

First, please bear with me. I have hard time telling others my problem and this is a long thread...

I am using pythonbrew to run multiple versions of python in Ubuntu 10.10. 
For installing pythonbrew and how it works, please refers to this link below

http://www.howopensource.com/2011/05/how-to-install-and-manage-different-versions-of-python-in-linux/

After reading a couple stackoverflow threads, I finally found the file called Setup under this directory:  **~/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.1/lib/python2.7/config**

```
In this Setup file I see 
# Andrew Kuchling's zlib module.
# This require zlib 1.1.3 (or later).
# See http://www.gzip.org/zlib/
# zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
```

I uncommented the last line, then I ran **python -v** again. However, I received the same error when I tried **import zlib**, so I guess I have to do something to install zlib into the lib.

But I am clueless about what I need to do. Can someone please direct me in the right direction??? Thank you very much!

I am doing this because I want to use different version of python in different virtualenv I created. 
When I did  **virtualenv -p python2.7** I received no module named zlib.

```
jwxie518@jwxie518-P5E-VM-DO:~$ virtualenv -p python2.7 --no-site-packages testenv

Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/jwxie518/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.1/bin/python2.7

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 17, in <module>
    import zlib

ImportError: No module named zlib
```

---

**EDIT**

I have to install 2.7.1 by appending --force.

I am developing Django, and I need some of these missing modules, for example sqlite3, and to create my virtualenv I definitely need zlib. If I just use the system default (2.6.6), I have no problem.

To do this with system default, all I need to do is

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages testenv
```

Thanks!

---

**(2nd edit)**

I installed 3.2 also and I tested it without problem, so I guess my problem comes down to how to install the missing module(s).

```
jwxie518@jwxie518-P5E-VM-DO:~$ virtualenv -p python3.2  testenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/jwxie518/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.2/bin/python3.2
New python executable in testenv/bin/python3.2
Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
Installing distribute..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...............done.
jwxie518@jwxie518-P5E-VM-DO:~$ virtualenv -p python3.2 --no-site-packages testenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /home/jwxie518/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.2/bin/python3.2
New python executable in testenv/bin/python3.2
Also creating executable in testenv/bin/python
Installing distribute..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Installing pip...............done.
```

Comment: the 3.2 is unnecessary i think. i just removed those contents. sorry. i was able to create the virtualenv with 3.2, but not 2.7.1

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Sounds like you need to install the devel package for zlib, probably want to do something like

```
# ubuntu 12,14,16,18,20.04+
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Instead of using python-brew you might want to consider just compiling by hand, it's not very hard. Just download the source, and `configure`, `make`, `make install`. You'll want to at least set `--prefix` to somewhere, so it'll get installed where you want.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python2.7 + other options
make
make install
```

You can check what configuration options are available with `./configure --help` and see what your system python was compiled with by doing:

```
python -c "import sysconfig; print sysconfig.get_config_var('CONFIG_ARGS')"
```

The key is to make sure you have the development packages installed for your system, so that Python will be able to build the `zlib`, `sqlite3`, etc modules. The python docs cover the build process in more detail: http://docs.python.org/using/unix.html#building-python.

Comment: thanks! hi. i will look into the rest now. but i just tried to install zlib1g-dev but it seems like i have that installed already (i tried a few other commands like -f install) zlib1g-dev is already the newest version. zlib1g-dev set to manually installed.

Comment: so far i get the good result. i am able to create with 2.7.1 using pythonbrew. i will check this as an answer once i am done with testing. thanks!!!

Comment: On Ubuntu, you can install all the Python build dependencies by running `sudo apt-get build-dep python` and/or `sudo apt-get build-dep python3`.

Comment: Correction:  `sudo apt-get build-dep python2.7` and `sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4`.

Comment: In centos 7 use $sudo yum install zlib-devel

Comment: Faced the same issue on osX, how to fix it? since not able to use `apt-get install xxx` to install zlib

Answer (score 31):

By default when you configuring Python source, zlib module is disabled, so you can enable it using option **--with-zlib** when you configure it. So it becomes

```
./configure --with-zlib
```

Comment: To be fair, the python `configure` used to provide a `--with-zlib` flag; it hasn't for quite some time, however.

Comment: Doesn't work in 2.7.6, I get configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-zlib

Comment: Not working with Python 3.2.5 -> found valid answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15013895/672848

Answer (score 29):

For the case I met, I found there are missing modules after make. So I did the following:

1. install zlib-devel
2. make and install python again.

Comment: to elaborate on that first step -- `sudo yum install zlib-devel` (centos)

Comment: It worked! I issued [ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev ] under ubuntu 12.04, re-make python 2.7.10 and it worked now. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

After running configure, you can change the config option in the file Modules/Setup as below:

```
zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
```

Or you can uncomment the zlib line as-is.

Comment: This was the only thing I found that worked for me when building python2.2 on Ubuntu 13.10. Kudos...

Comment: Also needed for Python 2.6

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support

Answer (score 4):

I had a lot of problems making a virtual environment (venv) as described in the [tensorflow installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip).

Most of the commands listed in this post didn't help me either so, if this is also your case this is what I did:

1. `pip3 install --user pipenv`
2. `pip install virtualenv`

Installs the dependencies to create a virtual environment

3. `mkdir myenv`

Makes a new directory called *myenv* but you can call it whatever you want e.g. *mynewenv*

4. `cd myenv`

Or whatever you call your directory so: cd [your_directory_name]

5. `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv`

Creates a virtual environment called *venv* in the folder *myenv*. You can call your virtual env whatever you like e.g. vitualenv [v_env_name]

6. `source ./venv/bin/activate`

Activates the virtual environment. Note that if you choose a different v. env. name your commands should be written as such *source ./[v_env_name]/bin/activate*

7. `deactivate`

Deactivates the virtual environment.

Note: I am using Python 3.6.6 & Ubuntu 18.04

[source for the commands](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)

Answer (score 3):

After you install the missing zlib dev package you can also use pythonbrew to uninstall and then reinstall the version of python you wanted and it seems like it picks up the new package to compile to correct abilities. This way you can keep using pythonbrew and don't have to do the compilation yourself (though it isn't that difficult)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answers here on CentOS or RHEL run

`sudo yum install zlib-devel`

The --with-zlib solutions shown here seem to be missing headers that Python 3.9 and up needs to link (in my case).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found, is given on [python.org](http://python.org) devguide:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.6
```

If that package is not available for your system, try reducing the minor version until you find a package that is available in your system’s package manager.

I tried explaining details, on [my blog](https://medium.elegantly.rocks/install-python-3-6-0-on-ubuntu-16-8cd6e369fd73#.iaxnsea7e).

Answer (score -1):

My objective was to create a new Django project from the command line in Ubuntu, like so:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I have python2.7.5 installed. I got this error:

```
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

For hours I could not find a solution, until now!

Here is a link to the solution -

http://doc.biblissima-condorcet.fr/loris-setup-guide-ubuntu-debian

I followed and executed instruction in Section 1.1 and it is working perfectly! It is an easy solution.