# How to compile Python 2.4.6 with ssl, readline and zlib on Debian Lenny

Tags: python, linux, ssl, debian, zlib

I have a virtual Linux box with Debian 7.1 where I need a Python 2.4.6 to reanimate an old Zope installation (in order to update it to Plone 4, of course).

I definitely need `ssl` support, and when I'm compiling, I want `readline` as well, of course.  Finally, of course I need `zlib`, otherwise `ez_setup.py` etc. won't work; I'm having a hard time to get `zlib` included.

I downloaded the tarball of Python 2.4.6, enabled `ssl` in `Modules/Setup.dist`:

```
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
        -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
        -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

... and called:

```
./configure  --prefix=/my/dest/dir --with-zlib
make
```

`make` gives me some warnings at the end about `crypt` and `nis`, but `make install` doesn't yield any errors.  However, the resulting Python features both `readline` and `ssl` support, but no `zlib`; thus, I can't use `ez_setup.py` to get setuptools/pip etc.

I tried both to uncomment and re-exclude the line

```
zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
```

from `Setup.dist`.

Some system packages which are installed:

- `zlib1g-dev`
- `lib32z1-dev`
- `libreadline-gplv2-dev`

Is there anything else I have missed?

**Update**, after heaving read https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047583/1051649:

I did

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev ncurses-doc
$ python setup.py clean
$ ./configure --with-ssl --with-zlib --prefix=...
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The resulting interpreter was not able to execute `distribute_setup.py`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911570/1051649):

I changed `setup.py`, looking for the first assignment to the lib_dirs variable, changing it like so:

```
lib_dirs = self.compiler.library_dirs + [
'/lib64', '/usr/lib64',
'/lib', '/usr/lib',
'/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu',   # added
'/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu',     # added
]
```

Then I repeated the whole thing, starting with `setup.py clean`, and it worked.