# Installing Python3.4.3: 3 tests failed, 3 altered execution environment and 25 skipped

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4

I use Lubuntu 14.04 as a guest OS (using VMplayer). I wanted to install python3.4.3. I downloaded the .tar.xz file from here:
https://www.python.org/downloads/

I then extracted the file and followed the instructions in the README:

```
./configure
make
make test
```

When I ran

```
make test
```

it returned this:

```
359 tests OK.
3 tests failed:
    test_urllib test_urllib2 test_urllib2net
3 tests altered the execution environment:
    test___all__ test_site test_warnings
25 tests skipped:
    test_bz2 test_curses test_dbm_gnu test_dbm_ndbm test_devpoll
    test_gdb test_gzip test_idle test_kqueue test_lzma test_msilib
    test_ossaudiodev test_readline test_smtpnet test_sqlite test_ssl
    test_startfile test_tcl test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_ttk_textonly
    test_winreg test_winsound test_zipfile64 test_zlib
Re-running failed tests in verbose mode
Re-running test 'test_urllib' in verbose mode
test test_urllib crashed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 1271, in runtest_inner
    the_module = importlib.import_module(abstest)
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_urllib.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'

Re-running test 'test_urllib2' in verbose mode
test test_urllib2 crashed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 1271, in runtest_inner
the_module = importlib.import_module(abstest)
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_urllib2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test import test_urllib
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_urllib.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'

Re-running test 'test_urllib2net' in verbose mode
test test_urllib2net crashed -- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/regrtest.py", line 1271, in runtest_inner
    the_module = importlib.import_module(abstest)
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_urllib2net.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test.test_urllib2 import sanepathname2url
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_urllib2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from test import test_urllib
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_urllib.py", line 13, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/home/ayman/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 97, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'

make: *** [test] Error 1
```

I'm not sure what these failed / skipped test effect me in the long run after I install Python3.4.3 with:

```
sudo make install
```

Should I be worried about these failed / skipped test? If yes, any idea on how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you were compiling Python without ssl or zlib support. That's the reason why some tests failed and some are skipped.

You may want to check out [How to compile Python 2.4.6 with ssl, readline and zlib on Debian Lenny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516956/how-to-compile-python-2-4-6-with-ssl-readline-and-zlib-on-debian-lenny) and [No module named zlib found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654707/no-module-named-zlib-found).