# Getting errors / failing tests when installing Python3.4.3 on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, installation, ubuntu-14.04, python-3.4

I use VMplayer and my OS is Lubuntu 14.04. It comes with a pre-installed python3.4.0 but I want to install python3.4.3. I downloaded the .tar.xz file from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/).

I then extracted the file and followed the instructions in the README:

```
./configure
make
make test
```

When I initially ran

```
make test
```

it said "3 tests failed, 3 altered execution environment and 25 skipped". I posted the question on SO here:
[Installing Python3.4.3: 3 tests failed, 3 altered execution environment and 25 skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872734/installing-python3-4-3-3-tests-failed-3-altered-execution-environment-and-25-s)

I then did

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

and did

```
./configure
make
```

again and it said:

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel      
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma              
_sqlite3              _tkinter              readline           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

Now when I tried

```
make test
```

it said

```
1 test failed:
    test_ssl
2 tests altered the execution environment:
    test___all__ test_warnings
21 tests skipped:
    test_bz2 test_curses test_dbm_gnu test_dbm_ndbm test_devpoll
    test_gdb test_idle test_kqueue test_lzma test_msilib
    test_ossaudiodev test_readline test_sqlite test_startfile test_tcl
    test_tk test_ttk_guionly test_ttk_textonly test_winreg
    test_winsound test_zipfile64
Re-running failed tests in verbose mode
Re-running test 'test_ssl' in verbose mode
test_ssl: testing with 'OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014' (1, 0, 1, 6, 15)
          under Linux ('debian', 'jessie/sid', '')
          HAS_SNI = True
          OP_ALL = 0x-7ffffc01
          OP_NO_TLSv1_1 = 0x10000000
test__create_stdlib_context (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_cert_store_stats (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_check_hostname (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_ciphers (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_constructor (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_create_default_context (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_get_ca_certs (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_load_cert_chain (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_load_default_certs (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_load_default_certs_env (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_load_default_certs_env_windows (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... skipped 'Windows specific'
test_load_dh_params (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_load_verify_cadata (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_load_verify_locations (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_options (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_protocol (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_session_stats (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_set_default_verify_paths (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_set_ecdh_curve (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_sni_callback (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_sni_callback_refcycle (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_verify_flags (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_verify_mode (test.test_ssl.ContextTests) ... ok
test_DER_to_PEM (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_asn1object (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_constants (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_dealloc_warn (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_enum_certificates (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... skipped 'Windows specific'
test_enum_crls (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... skipped 'Windows specific'
test_errors (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_get_default_verify_paths (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_match_hostname (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_openssl_version (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_parse_cert (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... 
{'issuer': ((('countryName', 'XY'),),
            (('localityName', 'Castle Anthrax'),),
            (('organizationName', 'Python Software Foundation'),),
            (('commonName', 'localhost'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Oct  5 23:01:56 2020 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Oct  8 23:01:56 2010 GMT',
 'serialNumber': 'D7C7381919AFC24E',
 'subject': ((('countryName', 'XY'),),
             (('localityName', 'Castle Anthrax'),),
             (('organizationName', 'Python Software Foundation'),),
             (('commonName', 'localhost'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'localhost'),),
 'version': 3}

{'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.verisign.com',),
 'caIssuers': ('http://SVRIntl-G3-aia.verisign.com/SVRIntlG3.cer',),
 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://SVRIntl-G3-crl.verisign.com/SVRIntlG3.crl',),
 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'US'),),
            (('organizationName', 'VeriSign, Inc.'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName', 'VeriSign Trust Network'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName',
              'Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10'),),
            (('commonName', 'VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Sep 20 23:59:59 2012 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Sep 21 00:00:00 2011 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '2EE6EA7640A075CEE5005F4D7C79549A',
 'subject': ((('countryName', 'FI'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', 'Espoo'),),
             (('localityName', 'Espoo'),),
             (('organizationName', 'Nokia'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName', 'BI'),),
             (('commonName', 'projects.developer.nokia.com'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'projects.developer.nokia.com'),
                    ('DNS', 'projects.forum.nokia.com')),
 'version': 3}
ok
test_parse_cert_CVE_2013_4238 (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... 
{'issuer': ((('countryName', 'US'),),
            (('stateOrProvinceName', 'Oregon'),),
            (('localityName', 'Beaverton'),),
            (('organizationName', 'Python Software Foundation'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName', 'Python Core Development'),),
            (('commonName', 'null.python.org\x00example.org'),),
            (('emailAddress', 'python-dev@python.org'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Aug  7 13:12:52 2013 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Aug  7 13:11:52 2013 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '00',
 'subject': ((('countryName', 'US'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', 'Oregon'),),
             (('localityName', 'Beaverton'),),
             (('organizationName', 'Python Software Foundation'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName', 'Python Core Development'),),
             (('commonName', 'null.python.org\x00example.org'),),
             (('emailAddress', 'python-dev@python.org'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'altnull.python.org\x00example.com'),
                    ('email', 'null@python.org\x00user@example.org'),
                    ('URI', 'http://null.python.org\x00http://example.org'),
                    ('IP Address', '192.0.2.1'),
                    ('IP Address', '2001:DB8:0:0:0:0:0:1\n')),
 'version': 3}
ok
test_purpose_enum (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_random (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... 
 RAND_status is 1 (sufficient randomness)
ok
test_random_fork (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_refcycle (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_server_side (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_timeout (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_tls_unique_channel_binding (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_unknown_channel_binding (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_unsupported_dtls (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_wrapped_unconnected (test.test_ssl.BasicSocketTests) ... ok
test_lib_reason (test.test_ssl.SSLErrorTests) ... ok
test_str (test.test_ssl.SSLErrorTests) ... ok
test_subclass (test.test_ssl.SSLErrorTests) ... ok
test_algorithms (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... 
Cipher with ('sha256.tbs-internet.com', 443) is ('RC4-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 128)
Certificate is:
{'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.tbs-x509.com',),
 'caIssuers': ('http://crt.tbs-internet.com/TBSX509CASGC.crt',
               'http://crt.tbs-x509.com/TBSX509CASGC.crt'),
 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl.tbs-internet.com/TBSX509CASGC.crl',
                           'http://crl.tbs-x509.com/TBSX509CASGC.crl'),
 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'FR'),),
            (('stateOrProvinceName', 'Calvados'),),
            (('localityName', 'Caen'),),
            (('organizationName', 'TBS INTERNET'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName',
              'Terms and Conditions: '
              'http://www.tbs-internet.com/CA/repository'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName', 'TBS INTERNET CA'),),
            (('commonName', 'TBS X509 CA SGC'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Feb 17 23:59:59 2016 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Feb 11 00:00:00 2014 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '1F94DEE8F046B340A6026500A4002CF8',
 'subject': ((('countryName', 'FR'),),
             (('postalCode', '14000'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', 'Calvados'),),
             (('localityName', 'CAEN'),),
             (('streetAddress', '22 RUE DE BRETAGNE'),),
             (('organizationName', 'TBS INTERNET'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName', '0002 440443810'),),
             (('organizationalUnitName', 'sha-256 production'),),
             (('commonName', 'sha256.tbs-internet.com'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'sha256.tbs-internet.com'),
                    ('DNS', 'www.sha256.tbs-internet.com')),
 'version': 3}
ok
test_ciphers (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_connect (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_connect_cadata (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_connect_capath (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_connect_ex (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_connect_ex_error (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_connect_with_context (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ERROR
/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/unittest/case.py:605: ResourceWarning: unclosed <ssl.SSLSocket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0, laddr=('192.168.174.253', 37135), raddr=('82.94.164.164', 443)>
  outcome.errors.clear()
test_context_setget (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_get_ca_certs_capath (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_get_server_certificate (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

Verified certificate for svn.python.org:443 is
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

skipped "Resource 'ipv6.google.com' is not available"
test_makefile_close (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_non_blocking_connect_ex (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_non_blocking_handshake (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... 
Needed 3 calls to do_handshake() to establish session.
ok
test_timeout_connect_ex (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests) ... ok
test_asyncore_server (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests)
Check the example asyncore integration. ... 
 server:  new connection from 127.0.0.1:57771
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server:  read b'FOO\n' from client
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
 client:  connection closed.
 cleanup: stopping server.
 cleanup: joining server thread.
 server:  read b'over\n' from client
 server:  closed connection <ssl.SSLSocket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=0>
 server:  read b'' from client
 cleanup: successfully joined.
ok
test_check_hostname (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ... 
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 47566)
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 47927)
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
ok
test_compression (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ...  server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 44281)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
 got compression: None
ok
test_compression_disabled (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ...  server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 44325)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
ok
test_crl_check (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ... 
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 42401)
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 39995)

 server:  bad connection attempt from ('127.0.0.1', 39995):
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_ssl.py", line 1532, in wrap_conn
    self.sock, server_side=True)
   File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
   File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 583, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
   File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 810, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
 ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:600)
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 55142)
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
ok
test_default_ciphers (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ... ok
test_default_ecdh_curve (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ...  server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 49676)
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
ok
test_dh_params (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ...  server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 45312)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
ok
test_do_handshake_enotconn (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests) ... ok
test_echo (test.test_ssl.ThreadedTests)
Basic test of an SSL client connecting to a server ... 
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 60169)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 57455)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 54910)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
 server: selected protocol is now None
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 client:  read b'foo\n'
 client:  closing connection.
 server:  new connection from ('127.0.0.1', 44655)
 client:  sending b'FOO\n'...
 server: connection cipher is now ('ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', 'TLSv1/SSLv3', 256)
======================================================================
ERROR: test_connect_with_context (test.test_ssl.NetworkedTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/test/test_ssl.py", line 1285, in test_connect_with_context
    s.connect(("svn.python.org", 443))
  File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 846, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 837, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/home/a/Downloads/python3.4.3/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ssl.py", line 810, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:600)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 99 tests in 85.177s

FAILED (errors=1, skipped=5)
test test_ssl failed
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

There was a bit more code in the middle but I deleted it because it would exceed the body limit. Nonetheless, the main thing is, 1 test failed, 2 tests altered the execution environment and 21 tests skipped.

Any idea why I'm getting failed and skipped tests even though I followed the exact steps on [the Python downloads page](https://www.python.org/downloads/)? Is there an easier way to install Python3.4.3 on my OS?

Comment: Why build from source? Why no]t apt-get install python3 ?

Comment: @AndyHayden will it be the exact same thing if I use apt-get? I simply Google'd "how to download python 3.4.3" and the first link was the python website (https://www.python.org/downloads/) which had the "download python 3.4.3" button. I clicked that, downloaded the file and then followed the instructions on the README. I never knew I would come across issues by following the instructions given by the Python website.

Comment: If you're using (L)ubuntu you should use apt-get. If you have downloaded the binary (e.g. the .deb from python.org) then you don't need to `make` (that's only if you are building from source - which you're not)...

Answer (score 3):

## Resolving OP Question

From the test Python has built OK. `"Python build finished successfully!"` The missing modules are there because you don't have the relevant software installed on your computer.

This is no different to using apt-get so for example your missing `_tkinter` this is because you don't have the packages necessary to run it. So if you were using `apt-get` you would have to use `apt-get install python-tk` so that `apt-get` would pull in the relevant dependencies. The logic being if you don't have the software installed your not going to need the modules to program it.

The only concern that I can see with the `make tests` is the failure of `ssl`.

```
1 test failed:
    test_ssl
```

looking down the test results you will see :-

```
test_ssl: testing with 'OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014' (1, 0, 1, 6, 15)
      under Linux ('debian', 'jessie/sid', '')
      HAS_SNI = True
      OP_ALL = 0x-7ffffc01
      OP_NO_TLSv1_1 = 0x10000000
```

This version of OpenSSL contains the SSL protocol vulnerability that was discover last year and was fixed in OpenSSL 1.0.1j [15 Oct 2014]. You can find this information [here](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.1-notes.html).

I am not really up on Ubuntu as I use Fedora but you could try :-

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And see if this fixes the SSL vulnerability that your computer has.

---

## Installing From Source

On a side note if your looking to develop Python apps for systems other than the one your using, installing from source is the only way to go.

There are many good reasons to compile from `tar.gz`.

1. most Linux distros use Python internally so are linked to a version.
2. you can get conflicts between modules that you import.
3. you can test your code against different versions of python.
4. you don't need root permissions set up your own versions so what you do is independent of anything the operating systems needs.

---

So for this example my home is `/home/paul` and I have created to directories in the root of my home. One call `src` which I will use as the source directory and one called `opt` that will hold my Python versions.

The trick is to tell Python where the install is to go. So put the `tar.gz` file in the `src` directory and expand it. Open the terminal and ...

```
cd ~/src/Python-X.X.X
./configure --prefix=/home/paul/opt/python.x.x.x
make
make test <optional>
make install
```

Note at no time did I use `sudo` as I have rights to my home directory and I am not effecting anything else on the system.

Now to test ...

```
~/opt/python.3.4.2/bin/python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Mar 28 2015, 19:36:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And you can just keep adding test versions as new versions come along just remember to start your code by pointing to the version you want to use.

Comment: @ReculsizeGeek you mentioned "On a side note if your looking to develop Python apps for systems other than the one your using, installing from source is the only way to go.". By this, do you mean that installing using the .tar.xz file is the way to go and is better than using apt-get to install it? If yes, how come?

Comment: Yes installing from the .tar.gz is the way to go.... Will post the reasons as an answer as it will need some explaining.

Comment: @ReclusizeGeek By the way, since it said "The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found: _bz2 _curses _curses_panel   _dbm    _gdbm   _lzma  _sqlite3   _tkinter  readline". Does this mean that if I do "sudo make install" then python 3.4.3 won't be installed properly because those necessary bits were not found? It seems weird to me that after I followed the instructions on the Python website / README file, it basically said "Python is installed except for these necessary bits". How will not having those necessary bits effect me in the long run?

Comment: @ReclusizeGeek also, I did apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade and it still gives the same tests failed, altered and skipped. Are there any other options for me to install Python 3.4.3? It doesn't seem like following the Python instructions and building from source is going to work without failing / altering / skipping tests.

Comment: @user2719875 Don't worry about "_bz2 _curses _curses_panel _dbm _gdbm _lzma _sqlite3 _tkinter readline" the only really worry is the SSL error but that is not going to stop you testing the build. Have you set the option "--prefix" on the configure ? ... if not just use the  instructions above and do the build in your home drive. Don't worry about the make test or any other errors and see if the build works. Let me know how you get on.

Comment: @user2719875 I have posted a blog as to why and how to over on Codrspace [link](http://codrspace.com/ReclusiveGeek/Building-python-from-source-the-why-and-how/)

Answer (score 2):

This command will pull in the necessary dependencies to build python 3.4 from source:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4
```

Also consider installing through pyenv to avoid creating a conflict with the OS. You can find installation instructions here : http://davebehnke.com/python-pyenv-ubuntu.html