# Python3.6 No module named '_curses'

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, python-3.6, python-curses

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and just installed Python3.6 manually (downloading the tar file). I already have Python2.7 and Python3.4 with Python2.7 the default one. With Python3.6, everything seems to be OK except when I run

```
import curses
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

Running

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev
sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev
```

did not work and neither did

```
pip3.6 install libncurses-dev
```

How do I install the curses module in python3.6?

Comment: perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373792/6084928

Comment: Thank you @LexScarisbrick. Turns out that the test phase has failed so _curses*.so files were not generated. I ran make test again and now it worked. I also made use of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886229/getting-errors-failing-tests-when-installing-python3-4-3-on-lubuntu-14-04