# building Python from source with zlib support

Tags: python, python-3.x

When building Python 3.2.3 from source on Ubuntu 12.04, the zlib module is not available.

I downloaded the official source distribution from python.org, and attempted to build and install it with the following commands.

```
tar xfa Python3.2.3.tar.bz2
cd Python-3.2.3
./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.2
make
sudo make install
```

The make command output includes the following.

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_curses            _curses_panel      _dbm            
_gdbm              _sqlite3           _ssl            
_tkinter           bz2                readline        
zlib
```

After running `make install` and starting the interpreter, the `zlib` module cannot be imported.

I confirmed that the `zlib1g-dev` package is installed on my system.

I also found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib), which suggests adding the `--with-zlib` flag to the `./configure` command.  However, that returns an error that it is an unrecognized option and has no effect.

Comment: I hope it's not bad form to answer my own question.  I spent several frustrating hours figuring this out, and the place where I finally found the solution (linked in my answer below) is pretty obscure.  Hopefully putting it here will make it easier for others to find.

Comment: I recommend running `sudo apt-get build-dep python` or similar before running configure + make to build your own Python from source.  That ensures you have all of the necessary development header files for the libraries Python likes to link to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is to install the Ubuntu package `dpkg-dev`.

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

The reason is explained [here](http://fnch.users.sourceforge.net/pythononubuntu1104.html).

In short, recent versions of Ubuntu don't store `libz.so` in the standard `/usr/lib` location, but rather in a platform specific location.  For example, on my system is is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`.  This prevents Python's build system from finding it.

The `dpkg-dev` package installs the `dpkg-architecture` executable, which enables Python to find the necessary libraries.

The original question was about Python 3.2.3.  I also downloaded Python 2.7.3 and confirmed that the same problem exists, and this solution is applicable to it as well.

Comment: dpkg-dev get's installed by build-essential, which are the essential tools for building *anything*. So you should really do `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. ;-)

Comment: To be fair, this answer is 6 years old, but on Ubuntu 18.04 this does NOT solve the zlib problem when building Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 101):

I had a similar problem on CentOS 6.3 and python 3.2.3

I solved it by:

Edit `/Modules/Setup` and uncomment the line:

```
zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz
```

change to directory /Modules/zlib:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

then compiled my python3.2 source.

and was then able to test import zlib and it all worked fine :)

Comment: Worked for me with 3.4.3

Comment: Worked for me on Python3.5.1. Thanks

Comment: Worked on 3.6.5 as well. Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a directory `/Modules/zlib` in Python 3.7.0. Also there is no `/Modules/Setup` - there is only a `/Modules/Setup.dist`, that contains the mentioned line. I changed the file, copied the file to `/Modules/Setup` and followed the other steps - but it didn't work for `3.7.0`, `3.6.5` or for `3.2.3`.

Comment: `/Modules/Setup` will be found where you have python. ex: `/opt/Python3.6.5`

Comment: Worked with CentOS 8 Linux (final release:) ) and python 3.9.16 With slight modification, I have added this line to ```Modules/Setup.local``` file and did ```dnf install gcc make libffi-devel openssl-devel zlib-devel bzip2-devel xz-devel``` after installation, did dnf history # and dnf history undo 24 # in my case was the line to remove all devel libraries.

Answer (score 20):

I am using CentOS 6.6 and was recieving zlib errors. None of the other answers proposed here worked for me (including the fix for CentOS 6.3 of uncommenting a line in Modules/Setup). I have fixed it using the following commands.

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel
```

Then configuring and installing python as follows:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

I can now import zlib in /usr/local/bin/python2.7 with no problems.

[These instructions are slightly modified from an article found here.](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/)

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who's trying to use a non-system / non-standard `zlib` (e.g. building your own from source), make sure to pass both `CPPFLAGS` (not `CFLAGS`!) and `LDFLAGS` to `./configure`. For example, if your `zlib` is in `/opt/zlib`:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/zlib/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/zlib/lib'
make
sudo make install
```

I ended up going down the rabbit hole trying to figure out why our Python wasn't building with zlib support and found out that the CPython `setup.py` does not look at `CFLAGS` for include dirs, only `CPPFLAGS`:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/setup.py#L562

Comment: permalink https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0198f52ea2328fd932622ad2299381f617a041f2/setup.py#L562

Answer (score 8):

The only solution that helped me with installing python 3.5.1 was to apt-get zlib1g-dev (and other packages such as python-setuptools and python-pip) and then rebuild python 3.5.1 from source.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-pip python-smbus
sudo apt-get install build-essential libncursesw5-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
cd ~
mkdir build
cd build
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.5.1.tgz
cd Python-3.5.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Taken from: https://github.com/MrYsLab/xideco/wiki/Installing-Python-3.5

As I undestand new build of python is made with inclusion of previously apt-getted related packages.
So when you browse the content of new Python-3.5.1/lib/site-packages there will be pip and setuptools. More importantly, they will be copied to any virtualenv you make using Python-3.5.1 AND this virtualenv will use THEM insted of system-default. This is very, **very important to rememmber** when installing new python version. Otherwise one might get into a black hole of errors such as:

- zlib not installed;
- "pip install ..." executed from virtualenv that installs package to system-default python instead of virtualenv.

Comment: This list helped a lot. I also ended up installing libreadline-gplv2-dev and libbz2-dev to fix warnings in python 3.7.3

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same error while working on  MAC

My MAC OS version

```
$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

python3.4 is used here

## Issue(s)

1. zlib not available while using python3.4

   $ python3.4 get-pip.py 
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "get-pip.py", line 20204, in 
       main()
     File "get-pip.py", line 152, in main
       bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
     File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
       import pip
   zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
2. Rebuilding Python fails

   ./configure  --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/lib

...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-zlib-dir
...

## Solution

1. Ensure zlib is installed .
   By default it will be installed in  /usr/lib

   ls /usr/lib/libz.*

If not installed, 
a. download and install 
i)from zlib.net site
or
ii) from a git repo like the below

```
git clone https://github.com/madler/zlib.git
```

or 
iii). Use the zlib source  in the python source directory 
Modules/zlib

b. Install zlib

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

2.Edit /Module/Setup by uncommenting the line below 
"#zlib zlibmodule.c -I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib -lz "

3.Rebuild the Python3.4 from source again

```
cd ${PYTHON_SRC_CODE_DIR}  
./configure --prefix=${PYTHON_HOME_DIR}
make
sudo make install
```

4.Confirm installation 
Please note gzip depends on zlib.

```
nbr_repeation=100
f=open("some_file.txt","at")
for line in range(nbr_repeation): 
    print('[{}] This file will be compressed using python zlib/gzipmodule'.format(line),file=f)

f.close()
f=open("some_file.txt","rt")
import gzip
gz=gzip.open('some_file.gz', 'wt') 
for line in f : gz.write(line)

gz.close() # Like to be clean exit
f.close()  # Like a clean exit

"""confirm the creation of the compressed gzip files"""
import os
print([ (file,os.stat(file)[6],"bytes") for file in os.listdir(".") if file.startswith("some")])
```

Answer (score 2):

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

Even though python-dev is for python2.7 it will still bring in all the necessary dependencies.

You will then need to do:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

To rebuild python3

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I found, is on [python.org](http://python.org):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python3.6
```

If that package is not available for your system, try reducing the minor version until you find a package that is available in your system’s package manager.

If you see something like this: `E: You must put some ‘source’ URIs in your sources.list`, Open Software & Updates and enable Source code.

I tried explaining details, on [a blog post](https://medium.elegantly.rocks/install-python-3-6-0-on-ubuntu-16-8cd6e369fd73#.iaxnsea7e).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same error on macOS Mojave, this is the easiest solution for installing/linking the header files:

```
open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

Then just build Python again as usual (also works with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) builds).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've built Python 3.7 on a CentOS 7 machine without devel libraries and installed it into user's `~/.local` without sudo. `zlib`, `OpenSSL` and `readline` modules are built.

Download Python source in .tgz format from https://www.python.org/downloads. Download `zlib-devel-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64.rpm`, `openssl-devel-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64.rpm`, `krb5-devel-1.15.1-50.el7.x86_64.rpm`, `libcom_err-devel-1.42.9-19.el7.x86_64.rpm`, `readline-devel-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm` from https://centos.pkgs.org for SSL, zlib and readline modules. Put all files into `$DIST_PATH`.

```bash
cd ~
DIST_PATH=<path to downloaded files>
for f in $DIST_PATH/*.rpm; do rpm2cpio $f | cpio -idmv; done
mkdir ~/usr/lib
# symlinks in ~/usr/lib64 are broken, so create new links to system libraries in ~/usr/lib and pass this folder to ./configure
for f in ~/usr/lib64/*.so; do ln -s /lib64/`readlink $f` ~/usr/lib/`basename $f`; done

tar -xzf $DIST_PATH/Python-3.7.13.tgz && cd Python-3.7.13
# That machine has devtoolset-7 with newer version GCC
scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
# curly brackets are important here, otherwise LDFLAGS is -LOME/usr/lib
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$HOME/.local --with-openssl=$HOME/usr CPPFLAGS='-I${HOME}/usr/include' LDFLAGS='-L${HOME}/usr/lib'
make
# (!) altinstall is used, use python3.7 command to access newly built Python
make altinstall

rm -rf ~/usr
```

Links:

- [Unpacking RPM packages](https://scicomp.ethz.ch/wiki/Unpacking_RPM_packages)
- [krb5.h error](https://www.cyrusimap.org/imap/reference/faqs/install-compilationerrors.html)
- [com_err.h](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=19)
- [CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54469348)