# Python 3: No module named zlib?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask, zlib

I am trying to run my Flask application with an Apache server using mod_wsgi, and it has been a bumpy road, to say the least.

It has been suggested that I should try to run my app's .wsgi file using Python to make sure it is working.

This is the contents of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

activate_this = '/var/www/Giveaway/Giveaway/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "somefile.py", 'exec')
    exec(code)

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/Giveaways/")

from Giveaways import application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'zlib'
```

And no, I am not using some homebrewed version of Python - I installed Python 3 via apt-get.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

does the contents of somefile.py include the gzip package? in which case you may have to install gzip package via pip or similar

Comment: Pip can't seem to find any package named "gzip". I've tried with both pip and pip3.

Comment: have you tried this?:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib

Comment: I have seen that answer, and have tried running `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`. It claims that it is already installed, yet I still receive the error with Python.

Comment: and do you have multiple python versions installed? zlib should be installed for the one used for your code above

Comment: Python 2.7 is installed by default, I believe, and I have installed 3.4 via apt-get - those are the only ones installed. Whilst running the program using 2.7 does not give me the error, the syntax of my code is incompatible with Python 2, thus I cannot run using only Python 2.

Comment: allright i believe this is the main issue, one potential solution is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support
beyond this I cannot really help you sorry

Comment: No such luck, I'm afraid.