# Building python (non-root) using zlib I built (non-root) on CentOS

Tags: python, linux, centos, zlib, rhel

I am using RHEL 6.8 (kernel 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64) and do not have root access.

I cannot build python2.7 with zlib support because zlib does not exist on my server and I an not root.
I am able to build zlib in a local directory, and I am also able to build python2.7 in a local directory without zlib support.

How can I now link to libz.a and libz.so in this local directory while building python?

I have tried multiple things based on searching online (rpath, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, uncommenting the zlib line in Modules/Setup.dist) but so far nothing has worked.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15013895/2970947

Comment: @Elliott Frisch: I saw that thread. All answers in that thread depend on the zlib that already exists on the system in /usr/local.  My problem is I do not have sudo rights, and zlib is does not already exist on my system, therefore I have to build zlib in my own local directory and somehow link to it (which is where I am having the problem)

Comment: You need to modify the `-I$(prefix)/include -L$(exec_prefix)/lib` bits, to point to the folder with your zlib header and zlib libraries respectively.