# Building Python 3.6.4 on Linux from scratch

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux-from-scratch

I'm trying to build Python 3.6.4 from LFS 8.2-systemd so I run the configure command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr       \
            --enable-shared     \
            --with-system-expat \
            --with-system-ffi   \
            --with-ensurepip=yes
```

followed by `make -j`.
However, at this point the module "pyexpat" is not found by Python, but the file exists in `/usr/lib/libexpat.so`.

After reading [building Python from source with zlib support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support), I created a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-gnu-linux
```

If i run `make install`, I get an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pyexpat

My expat lib version is `2.2.5`.

I'm doing the compilation inside `env -i chroot /mnt bash`
and my environment just contains a valid `PATH` and `LX_ALL=POSIX` variables.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem for python 3.6.8 , when I initially configured using:

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/python-3.6/ --enable-optimizations

However, when I retried using the command in the BLFS book:

> ./configure --prefix=/opt/python-3.6/ --enable-shared --with-system-expat --with-system-ffi --with-ensurepip=yes

My pyexpat started working.

That being said, I think it may be helpful to just retry, since my second command is functionally identical to yours.

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

To make python3 use the new installed python 3.6 instead of the default 3.5 release, run following 2 commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2
```

Finally switch between the two python versions for python3 via command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

After selecting version 3.6:

```
python3 -V
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). (see my edit)

Comment: This is Linux From Scratch. The system almost certainly does not have `apt`.