# How do I build zlib.pyd?

Tags: python, zlib, cpython

I have a py2exe built program which is failing because it needs a copy of zlib.pyd.  How do I build this?  I can create zlib.dll (or .lib) from source, I can compile Python from source, I've worked with distutils, py2exe, and pyinstaller a pretty decent amount, so I have a good feel for the "landscape" - but I'm not sure how to go about directly generating a .pyd like this.

Update:

I found this:

[building Python from source with zlib support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support)

Which seems to be the answer for Linux, but this is not quite applicable in Windows using `nmake`...

Comment: Are you running py2exe against a standard install of Python? If so, you almost certainly just want to get py2exe to copy the existing `zlib.pyd` out of the stdlib, not build a new copy of it.

Comment: if you really _do_ need to build a copy of it, assuming you want to build the one out of the CPython source tree, IIRC it's a matter of editing `Modules/Setup.local`, copying in the `zlib` section from `Modules/Setup`, uncommenting it, and then you can… I don't know the last step on Windows (on *nix, it's a `make` command…).

Comment: Thanks @abarnert.  I'll check that out.  There is no zlib.pyd by the way packaged with a standard install of Python.  Nor does CPython naturally build one.  Hence the question!  I did find an old random copy floating around the web, but when I tried that it failed because it wanted to talk an old version of the base python.dll.  So, you are right that there needs to be version matching.

Comment: On Windows, it seems the file is Setup.dist.  Else, that's a Python version discrepancy.  I'm working with v.2.7.  There is already a zlibmodule line there in a comment. I uncommented it, ran the build, everything succeeded, but there is no .pyd to be found!  I'm trying to use distutil now, to build an extension from the zlibmodule.c file directly.  I almost have that working, but am running into linker errors...

Comment: `zlib` has been part of the Python stdlib since 1.5 or so. If there's no `zlib.pyd`, it must be linked into the interpreter (in `python27.dll`), in which case you shouldn't need it in your py2exe app. Can you `import zlib` from within Python? If so, I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here.

Comment: I've come to think you're right that zlib is simply rolled into the interpreter.  Yet, when I package this dll I'm working on, it fails and using Dependency Walker reveals the cause is a LoadLibraryA failure with zlib.pyd.  Without that file present, it claims that dependency is missing.  I managed to build one now, in a round about ugly manner, but it is still failing, despite being found...

Comment: As a test, I just built a tiny exe (rather than a dll) using py2exe, which simply runs a zlib test.  That exe works, and there is no zlib.pyd required.  I'm going to try something similar with a dll now.  Unfortunately, in my actual use case I have a substantial library being imported that comes from Google.  I have no idea where and how they use zlib.

Comment: Ugh... Yeah I have a dll (com server) example now using zlib directly and it works without any issue.  It definitely seems Dependency Walker threw a red herring my way!