# Cross-Compile Python with zlib support

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling, zlib

I'm trying to cross-compile python with zlib support.

What I did and what is working:

- Downloaded Python source code (Python-3.6.5)
- Compiled zlib from Python folder:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Path to angstrom cross-compiler
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/angstrom/arm/bin

CC=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ AR=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar LD=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ld \
        RANLIB=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ranlib \
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$HOME/python \
    --enable-shared
```

- Copied compiled zlib library files to angstrom compiler location, just to be sure it is found.
- Configure Python:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Path to angstrom bin folder
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/angstrom/arm/bin

CC=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-g++ AR=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ar LD=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ld \
        RANLIB=$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-ranlib \
    ./configure --host=arm-angstrom-linux --target=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi \
    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/python \
    READELF==arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-readelf \
    --disable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no \
    ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes --enable-shared
```

- Activate zlib in Modules/Setup like discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344970/building-python-from-source-with-zlib-support).
- make & make install

```
#!/bin/sh

# Path to angstrom bin folder
CROSS_COMPILE=/home/toolchain/angstrom/arm/bin

make HOSTPYTHON=$HOME/python \
BLDSHARED="$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared" CROSS-COMPILE=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabihf- \
CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes HOSTARCH=arm-angstrom-linux BUILDARCH=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabihf

make altinstall HOSTPYTHON=$HOME/python \
BLDSHARED="$CROSS_COMPILE/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -shared" CROSS-COMPILE=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabihf- \
CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes HOSTARCH=arm-angstrom-linux BUILDARCH=arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabihf \
prefix=$HOME/python
```

The output of the make process states zlib was not compiled:

```
Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _curses               _curses_panel
_dbm                  _gdbm                 _lzma
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter
readline              zlib
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

Copying the compiled modules to the arm device, shows Python working but without zlib support.

Comment: I found the following bug report from python https://bugs.python.org/issue28444. I will setup a fresh VM and see if it works.

Comment: Did it work? I'm strugglin with the same now...

Answer (score 2):

Python will detect zlib and other dependencies in `setup.py`. Before detecting, it will search for valid include dirs and library dirs in `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. So try set `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` like below while configuring Python:

```sh
CC=blah CXX=blah AR=blah LD=blah RANLIB=blah \
CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/python/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/python/lib" \
    ./configure blahblah
```

Comment: This is the answer. setup.py uses CPPFLAGS and not CXXFLAGS. Thanks a lot!