# ImportError: No module named zlib

Tags: python, boto

I am getting this error while running a python script to send file on S3

```
File "docs/setup/s3transfer.py", line 121, in <module>
    main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "docs/setup/s3transfer.py", line 28, in main
    conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key, sceret_key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/__init__.py", line 140, in connect_s3
    from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 30, in <module>
    from boto.auth import detect_potential_s3sigv4
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 34, in <module>
    import boto.utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/utils.py", line 57, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

although when i do

```
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

I get :

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.myfahim.com
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: centos.myfahim.com
 * updates: centos.myfahim.com
Package zlib-devel-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: `pip install zlib`

Comment: what does `which zlib` return, its probably not in the path

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829507/virtualenv-no-module-named-zlib ?

Comment: @DmitryPolonskiy /usr/bin/which: no zlib in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but in case someone finds this, like I did, I had the same issue with an older script that requires python3.5.  After a recent update of MacPorts, it brought my py3.5 up to 3.5.10_5  I'd tried multiple fixes, and none of them worked.  With MacPorts, activating a specific version will deactivate other versions.  So, I tried the previous release, and the script started working again.

I ran:

```
sudo port installed python35 
  The following ports are currently installed:
    python35 @3.5.10_4
    python35 @3.5.10_5 (active)
```

Followed by:

```
sudo port activate python35 @3.5.10_4
--->  Computing dependencies for python35
--->  Deactivating python35 @3.5.10_5
--->  Cleaning python35
--->  Activating python35 @3.5.10_4
--->  Cleaning python35
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this recently on centos 7
This should help

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
sudo make
sudo make altinstall
```