# virtualenv in python 2.7, ubuntu 10.04

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have installed python 2.7 in ubuntu 10.04:

```
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
```

Python works properly:

```
~$ python2.7
Python 2.7 (r27:82500, Mar  6 2013, 15:39:19)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But:

```
~$ virtualenv -p python2.7 ~/virtualenv/python27
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1378, in <module>
    """.decode("base64").decode("zlib")
LookupError: unknown encoding: zlib.
```

WTF?

Comment: Did that `make` return a line telling you it couldn't find the bits needs to make certain libraries, one of which is zlib?

Comment: possible duplicate of [no module named zlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)

Answer (score 1):

You are using virtualenv of the 2.6 python:
check your lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/virtualenv.py"
```

Do you have virtualenv installed in the python2.7? normally is named virtualenv2.7 if you have both.