# How can I create a project on Django using Elementary os?

Tags: python, django, linux

I'm having troubles when I try to create my project on Django.

Error message:

```
django-admin.py startproject car

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line


    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute


    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command

    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module

    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management.templates import TemplateCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 20, in <module>


    from django.template import Template, Context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>


    from django.template.base import (ALLOWED_VARIABLE_CHARS, BLOCK_TAG_END,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 12, in <module>

    from django.utils.text import (smart_split, unescape_string_literal,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/text.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gzip import GzipFile

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>

    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

(I already  have Python 2.7 and Django 1.5.1 installed)

Comment: possible duplicate of [no module named zlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)

Comment: -1 for posting screenshot instead of cutting and pasting the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read your errors more carefuly.

```
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I don't figure out how to fix that error, I've been looking for that error on Internet but I don't find  nothing useful.