# Django ImportError: No Module named zlib

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to develop in Django 1.5. Whenever I enter the command into the Linux terminal (I am running Ubuntu 13.04, and Python 2.7.5):

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/startproject.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management.templates import TemplateCommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/templates.py", line 20, in <module>
    from django.template import Template, Context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from django.template.base import (ALLOWED_VARIABLE_CHARS, BLOCK_TAG_END,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.utils.text import (smart_split, unescape_string_literal,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/text.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gzip import GzipFile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

I have already looked on the web to figure this out, no luck whatsoever.

Thanks in advance,
Nicholas

Comment: What is the value of `sys.path` (check it eg. like this: `import sys; print(sys.path)`)?

Comment: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Answer (score 0):

You need the development versions. See this past question  for complete details [no module named zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)

Comment: I went through that thread, and it did not help me at all. :/

Comment: does apt-get zlibc  fix things for you.  There are lots of similar questions related to this issue with Ubuntu 10.04 lucid

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, though I was just trying to get the default Django site up.

Environment details: 
Python 2.7.5 Django 1.5.4

1. Re-Installed all the zlib files: "*sudo apt-get install --reinstall
   zlibc zlib1g zlib1g-dev"*
2. Re-install/compile my python 2.7.5 installation, as python needs the zlib module to be already present so that it is able to build the packages. The hint was in
   [no module named zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib?rq=1)
3. Made sure my PYTHONPATH within .bashrc was still intact.
4. ran $python manage.py runserver == Success !!!

Again this worked for me, so YMMV...