# Installing python locally with a custom numpy source

Tags: python, numpy, build, installation

Linux Beginner Level - Please answer accordingly!

I do not have root privileges at my work computer. I installed a local version of python2.7.6 recently in a directory i can access (the version of python in /usr/lib is python 2.7.3!). But it does not have the numpy modules with it. Do I have to build numpy separately, or can i link to the existing numpy modules I already have from the root installation?

Comment: [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) comes to the rescue

Comment: problem with zlib - it is not installed in the local python-2.7.6 version!

Comment: As @alko suggested, virtualenv is a great solution. You can also use `pip install --user numpy` to install numpy to your local version, or if you need to install from source, go to the numpy source directory and `python setup.py install --user`.

Comment: virtualenv is indeed a great solution. thanks for mentioning it @alko. 
[This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib) was very helpful for me! I would implore you to consider making this an answer for those who come looking and go away without realizing that this is answered!