# Unable to install Image package in Python (Windows) - zlib is required

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pycharm, zlib

I am using PyCharm with Python 3.0 and I want to import Image Module.

While installing the Image module from Project Interpreter, I got a message which says:

```
ValueError: zlib is required unless explicitly disabled using --disable-zlib, aborting.
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEdDS.png)

There is no package named Zlib to install.

I tried to find several solution, but most of them are for Linux. for example, this solution: [no module named zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)

How can I solve this issue in Windows and with PyCharm ?

Answer (score 2):

easy_install Pillow
 - this will install dependencies automatically

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I wanted to install Mezzanine.

Solution was to install pillow by 
- downloading the Windows package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/3.4.2, and 
- installing with "pip install .
Please make sure that you download the correct pillow package for your Python version.
After that, I could install Mezzanine without error.