# "ImportError: No module named zlib" when install google cloud sdk

Tags: macos, google-cloud-sdk

I'm installing google cloud sdk on mac following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive). But I failed when trying to run this command:

```
$ curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
```

And this is error:

```
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 44, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/credentials/store.py", line 32, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import http
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/http.py", line 31, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import http_proxy
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/http_proxy.py", line 26, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from httplib2.python2.httplib2 import *
  File "/Users/tran.ba.vinh.son/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    import gzip
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gzip.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named zlib
```

I tried with `Homebrew` but same error:

```
brew cask install google-cloud-sdk
```

And even after install `zlib` via `brew install zlib`. I still got that error. Please help me if you have any suggestions, thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [no module named zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169522/no-module-named-zlib)

Comment: Same here. gcloud started to fail (not only the installation but also running the existing version) after upgrading Python with brew yesterday for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [comment](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/29176#issuecomment-398656987) on `homebrew core` that fixed it for me.

TL;DR ->
`sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /`

I had this issue when installing `asdf` as well. I ran the command above and then `brew install asdf` worked. I think this issue happens after a macOS update because I had to run it again to install `google-cloud-sdk`.

Comment: That didn't work for me. gcloud installation still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Developer Command Line Tools** :

```
xcode-select --install
```

Reinstall **python2** :

```
brew reinstall python2
```