ModuleNotFoundError: No package named 'zlib'
I am trying to run a Python3.11.3 program on my chromebook. I was able to install Python3.11.3 using a tar.gz file and unpacking it, then running the commands:
./configure --prefix=/user/local/Python-3.11.3.
make
sudo make install

I am able to download any packages I want using Pip3 as well. However, when I try to run a program, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'.
I've installed it multiple times using sudo apt install zlib1g-dev, but this doesn't solve the problem. Output of running that command is as follows:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-2+deb11u2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Here are the details for the OS I'm running:
Google Chrome   113.0.5672.134 (Official Build) (32-bit) 
Revision    310cab01819b3d36f28dd73596f3a8dd0ad0c52e-refs/branch-heads/5672@{#1221}
Platform    15393.58.0 (Official Build) stable-channel kukui
Firmware Version    Google_Krane.12573.271.0
Customization ID    krane
ARC 10061634 SDK Version: 28

Please let me know if you need more information, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

few solution to try, after installing zlib1g-dev, try compile and install python again, or try compiling with the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9486138/16912844

It seems that Python does not include zlib by default, per this answer, so you have to ask for it when compiling.

Does this answer your question? no module named zlib
